# Liquibase update or liquibase migrate?

Tags: liquibase

What is the difference b/t `liquibase ... migrate` and `liquibase ... update` ?

I cannot find any documentation on the `migrate` command at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`migrate` is a simply an (undocumented) alias for `update`:

```
687 if (this.command.equalsIgnoreCase("migrate")) {
688     this.command = "update";
689 }
```

[liquibase.integration.commandline.Main](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.4.1/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#687)

Comment: meanwhile, the migrate command is deprecated at least for maven-plugin since org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.8:migrate https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-migrate.html